# How to cancel the windows shortcut key when I use emacs 24.3 in gui in windows?

Tags: windows, emacs, shortcut

I download the emacs 24.3 in http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/windows/

In a gui mode, I found the following trouble. So I want to cancel the windows shortcut key

The 1st example is that I define the shortcut "C-F2" in linux and I also want to use it in windows.

The 2nd example "C-space" makes me to mark things but it is not working in windows. It is obvious that emacs are occupied by the windows shortcuts. How can I cancel the windows shortcut key when I use emacs in windows?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? In a graphical window or inside `cmd.exe`? How did you install it?

Comment: @Chris, "correct it" means that I edit my questions to be more understanding. But my question is not solved. %>_<%

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I don't think that those are standard Windows shortcuts. What do they do? Also, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179119/how-to-prevent-windows-xp-from-stealing-my-input-ctrl-space-which-is-meant-for-e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect these are not taken by Windows itself, but by your IME. It may be possible to change the keys in the IME Settings.